# How to deal with $f(z_{k+1})$ term?

Tags: numerical-methods

The method for roots of a scalar function $f$ alternates Newton steps ($x_k\mapsto z_{k+1}$) and simplified Newton steps ($z_{k+1}\mapsto x_{k+1}$).

[image: This is the question]

I think I need to Taylor expand all the f, but I do not know how to deal with the $f(z_{k+1})$ term. Seems like Taylor expanding that is very hard. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: There's something odd about the question. What if $f$ has two (or more) roots. How do the $x_k$ know which one they are supposed to converge to?

Comment: @GerryMyerson : When asking for the order, the assumption usually is that the sequence in consideration already converges to a root. Asking which initial points lead to convergence is a different, much more difficult question.

Comment: Ups, looks like I got one-shot duplicates for [numerical-methods] too. Look at the link and report back if you think your question is different, I'll also vote for re-opening.